# Why won't a character sprite show up in Python?

Tags: python

I'm new to making stuff with Python, so I followed and tutorial on how to make a game with Python. I've run my code through multiple AIs, and they say it doesn't have any problems, but it doesn't work. What it is supposed to do is show an image on a blue background, but it only shows a blue background. My code:

```py
import pygame
import math
import time
height = 800
width = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test Game")

def character():
    character = pygame.image.load(FILE_PATH)
    character_rect = character.get_rect()
    character_rect.center = (width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.blit(character, character_rect)
def bgImg():
    bg = screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
def running():
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        bgImg()
        character()
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    running()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you don't update the screen once the character gets drawn. If `pygame.display.update()` isn't called, then no changes to the screen will be shown. You have to call `pygame.display.update()` inside the character function too. Modified function:

```
def character():
    character = pygame.image.load(FILE_PATH)
    character_rect = character.get_rect()
    character_rect.center = (width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.blit(character, character_rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Alternatively, as @Grismar suggested, you can put `pygame.display.update()` outside the function in the while loop. This is a better method as it doesn't require adding `pygame.display.update()` inside every function. Modified code:

```
....
def character():
    character = pygame.image.load(FILE_PATH)
    character_rect = character.get_rect()
    character_rect.center = (width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.blit(character, character_rect)
def bgImg():
    bg = screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
    #Remove the update function from here

def running():
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        bgImg()
        character()
        pygame.display.update() #Call the update function after calling every other function

    pygame.quit()
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this line in the routine that draws the background:

```
        pygame.display.update()
```

However, you don't include that in the routine the draws the character. As a result, the background gets drawn, the screen gets updated, the character gets 'drawn' but the screen never updates before the background gets drawn again.

Instead, something like this works:

```
import pygame
import math
import time
height = 800
width = 1000
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test Game")

def character():
    ch_img = pygame.image.load("test.png")
    character_rect = ch_img.get_rect()
    character_rect.center = (width // 2, height // 2)
    screen.blit(ch_img, character_rect)

def bgImg():
    screen.fill((0, 0, 255))

def running():
    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                break
        # paint things
        bgImg()
        character()
        # update the screen
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    running()
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I was getting a headache from this.